# How do you control both teams in a StarCraft 2 unit tester map?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to try out the unit tester map 818 by doc which I've seen being used in quite a number of tutorials, but the question is I can't seem to control both teams. How do I do that?

I search for it in custom games and if I play solo, it's victorious screen right after it loads, even if I set computer, it just doesn't let me control the other team?

Comment: I don't know the unit tester in question but some unit tester maps have 2 versions, 1 for one player controlling both teams, 1 for two players. Maybe there is another version?

Comment: Are you hosting this in multiplayer or single player mode? I believe most of the custom maps only work in multiplayer.

Comment: Im hosting it online? or multiplayer? and it says "you can control both team Blue and Red [and] solo play only" in the description. Ive no idea what Im doin wrong

Answer (score 3):

Here is the unit tester I use. I am not sure if this is the one you reference, but it is possible to control both teams.

First search for the unit tester by searching for "unit tester" on the multiplayer custom games screen. Select "[Official] Unit Tester Online" and start the game immediately (you should be the only one in team 1).

[image]

The game will confirm that you control both teams.

[image]

Select the units for both teams from the menus and click on Start.

[image]

Now you can control both teams by just selecting the units and issuing commands. It is as if all units belong to you, but they will attack each other if they stand nearby.

Comment: This map is hosted on EU. I am quite sure that the US servers have the same map, but the name might differ.